# External user with permission can't access site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I've invited a external user to a site on my sharepoint but the user get the request access page when trying to access.
/sites/Test/testsite

When checking the permissions for the external user on the site it confirms that he has Read permission and should be able to access the site.

In Sharepoint admin center:

-Policies / sharing is set to "New and existing guests"
-Policies / Limit external sharing by domain and correct domain is added
-Sites / active sites, the parent site (/sites/Test) has "External sharing" set to "on"

In Azure Active Directory:

-The external user exists as a guest user. Source "External Azure AD"

I've tried to remove the user and add him again.
I've tried to approve access requested asked from the the "you need permission"- page. I've get a "Request approved" but it's not working.

Not sure what setting I got wrong here

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens if the site collection feature "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" is activated.

Go to site settings-> site collection features, deactivate the feature "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode". Check if it works for you.